# How to implement a conditional match stage in the aggregate pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a stage which looks like this

```
{
  $match: { isLive: true },
}
```

and an external variable of `isAdmin`.

If `isAdmin` I want to bypass the stage.
If `!isAdmin` I want to run the stage.

Essentially like a short-circuit operator

```
{
  !isAdmin && $match: { isLive: true },
}
```

I've tried many combinations of operators but I just can't get it to work (I'm very new to Mongo). I'm sure it's very simple but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
const pipeline = [];
if (!isAdmin) pipeline.push({ $match: { isLive: true } });
pipeline.push({ $project: { _id: 1 } });

db.collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```

You may use also other [Array methods](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp) to compose your pipeline.

Or try

```
{ $match: { $expr: { $or: [isAdmin, "$isLive"] } } }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Perfect! Thank you kindly